# How to delete tags from a large number of files

Tags: macos, finder-tag

I have created by accident about 70 tags. by copying them into the finder tag window by accident.

I am using only 6 of them.

How can I delete all the 70 tags except those 6?

I tried to do it from finder but the process is so slow. I would choose some another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete custom tags you created by going to "Finder-->Preferences-->Tags"  Then highlight the tags you don't want.  (To select multiple at once click one and then shift+click the last one).  Right-click and "Delete # Tags".

[image]

In your case, with 70+ tags, just use select all from the edit menu (Command A) to select all the tags. Then hold the option key to click the 6 tags you want to keep. Once the rest are selected you can mass delete them, leaving the few tags you prefer.

Comment: What I want is to delete the unused 70 tags...

Comment: I see, so you want to get rid of the custom tags you created, not tags on files?  Edited above answer.

Comment: Nice answer. I was also confused initially that the tags were on the files and not that it was a "tag management" issue that could be deleted easier.

Comment: :) Thanks @tron_jones I accepted your answer (In the meantime I figured it out, but you deserve the point)